# Android SensorManager.java getOrientation and getRotationMatrix algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, math, orientation, physics

I am trying to figure out how `getRotationMatrix()` and `getOrientation()` work exactly.

So far I've known that in `getRotationMatrix()` function it crossproducts the gravity vector with the magnetic vector to get the new vector pointing to the East. And then , it crossproducts the East vector with the gravity vector again to get the vector pointing to the magnetic north. According to this [article](http://www.physicsforums.com/archive/index.php/t-333207.html) said, now we have three orthogonal vectors and we can form a rotation matrix.

Here is my **first question**: Why we should crossproduct the East vector with gravity vector again to get a vector pointing the magnetic north? Isn't the original magnetic vector pointing the magnetic north? what are the difference between new vector and the original magnetic vector?

Speaking about the `getOrientation()`, here is my **second question**: how do the azimuth, roll and pitch come out? Are there any equations or formula for explanation?

you can go to this [website](http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/9cb3e09ec49351401cf19b5ae5092dd9ca90a538/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java)  to see the code

very appreciated for your attention. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First answer: The magnetic vector points (magnetic) North and maybe also somewhat up or down. The purpose of the second cross product is to get a vector in the horizontal plane, pointing (magnetic) North.

Second answer: According to that code, roll pitch and azimuth are calculated from elements of the rotation matrix, which in turn are derived from components of the three spacial vectors. At a glance,

tan(azimuth) = M<sub>y</sub>/H<sub>y</sub>
sin(pitch)   = -A<sub>y</sub>
tan(roll)    = -A<sub>z</sub>/A<sub>x</sub>

(Whether that's sufficient answer depends on how comfortable you are with trigonometry and visualizing rotations in 3-space.)

Comment: Dear Beta: Thanks for your answer, I am sorry for not making it clear about my second question. I know the three angles are coming from the rotation matrix, but WHY they look like that? they must be derived from somewhere . I want to know the principle or formula behind these equations.   Thank you!!